# Let $G$ be a simple graph. Show that $m\leq {n \choose 2}$, and determine when equality holds.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

I'm reading Bondy and Murthy's *Graph Theory*, and I'm doing the proposed exercise in the title. I've tried to do the following:

> $m$: Edges
>
> $n$: Vertices

A simple graph with $n$ vertices has a maximum of $m=(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+(n-n)$ and hence

$$m=(n-1)n-\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}=\frac{n^2-n}{2}$$

Which is $(n-1)$ times the number of $n$'s and the sum of the first $(n-1)$ natural numbers. Knowing that the maximum number of edges in a simple graph is ${n \choose 2}$, we can write:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {m}&\leq&{{n \choose 2}}\\
  {}&&{}\\
  {\frac{n^2-n}{2}}&\leq&{\frac{n!}{2(n-2)}}\\
  {}&&{}\\
  {n^2-n}&\leq&{\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}}\\
  {}&&{}\\
  {n^2-n}&\leq&{n \cdot (n-1)}\\
  {}&&{}\\
  {n^2-n}&\leq&{n^2-n}\\
  {}&&{}\\
  {n^2-n}&\leq&{n^2-n}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Your algebra is incorrect: $$(n-1)n-\frac{(n-1)n}2=\frac{n^2-n}2=\frac{n(n-1)}2\;.$$ How is this related to $\binom{n}2$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was counting the number of edges and trying to associate with $\binom{n}2$, given that I know that the maximum number of edges is that.

Comment: If you know that the maximum possible number of edges is $\binom{n}2$, then $m=\binom{n}2$ if and only if $G$ is what kind of graph?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott $K_n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, I've corrected the algebra and now I see it. I was confused with my result.

Comment: Excellent. Yes, if $G$ has the maximum possible number of edges, it must be $K_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $m\gt{n\choose 2}$ where the order and size of $G$ is $n$ and $m$, respectively. We know that $K_n$ has exactly ${n\choose 2}$ edges. Since $m\gt{n\choose 2}$ this implies that $G$ contains at least $1$ multiple edge which contradicts the fact that $G$ is simple. Thus for all simple graphs $G$ we know that $m\leq {n\choose 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

An edge in a simple graph can be thought of as a set of two vertices (its end points), there is $ {n \choose 2} $ sets of size two from the set of vertices. If $X$ is the set of vertex subsets of size 2 then the edge set $E$ is a subset of $X$ so $m = |E| \leq |X| = {n \choose 2} $